# Typescript - Class Instance Variable As An Accessor To The First Value In A Set

Tags: javascript, typescript, anonymous-function, instance-variables

In a typescript class, are you able to specify an instance variable as a shortcut to access the first value in a Set?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
export class Car {
    public gears: Set<string>;
    public gear: string => gears?.values().next().value; // doesn't work

    constructor() {
        gears = new Set<string>(["N", "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var car = new Car();
console.log(car.gear); // => "N"
```

I know you can do it with a function like

```
public gear = (): string => gears?.values().next().value;
```

But when you call that you need to call it as a function instead of an instance variable

```
var car = new Car();
console.log(car.gear()); // => "N"
```

While that works, it's not ideal because semantically it doesn't make a lot of sense that `gear` is a function.

Is what I'm asking possible in Typescript?

Comment: You're looking for "getter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a getter :

```
export class Car {
    public gears: Set<string>;
    public get gear(): string {
        return this.gears.values().next().value
    }

    constructor() {
        this.gears = new Set<string>(["N", "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEVTgbwCg4S4wBXAIyQEsE4BzYXNALjgGVgYAeNGKDQB2DAHwBuYqQrU6jbvNwAKAJTt%20gkQSmlSUbuShC4MABY00AOiYtLANxRJywNKstDQMNw6fAdcAF9CfwQIIQ1yBBhoVW1dXTMLa2YoTABeOA8Ad05uPgFhMSUAbQAiADlSgBo4UoAxGlSYatquUKEAExbSgBVzKC6a%20ohDM1KAXRVJXSCAoA)